# Data filters on Related Syncronised Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

I am using both MC and SC which are sync'ed using the Connector.

I have an Account Object and an Opportunity Object that I would like to segment against.

The filter criteria goes like this

```
    ACCOUNT WHERE 
    (OPPORTUNITY.CLOSEDATE = 2019 AND OPPORTUNITY.AMOUNT > 200.00) 
AND (OPPORTUNITY.CLOSEDATE = 2018 AND OPPORTUNITY.AMOUNT > 1000.00)
```

The idea is I'm trying to find accounts that have multiple opportunities that meet certain conditions this year and last year. The problem is when I set them in subsets like I have above it returns no results, however if I do them individually (with closedate and amount together) they yield results.

Can anyone explain why this happens? and how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the expected behavior would be no result.

Regardless of "amount" - You are looking for one individual Account with opportunity.closedate 2018 AND 2019 at the same time.

This will never match, as the value would always be either 2018 / or 2019 on that same record.

You want to combine *results*, not queries on the same record.

I think this only makes sense in a two-stage approach - 
Two selects and a UNION (all) on the result.

```
SELECT FROM ACCOUNT WHERE
OPPORTUNITY.CLOSEDATE = 2019 AND OPPORTUNITY.AMOUNT > 200.00

UNION (ALL)

SELECT FROM ACCOUNT WHERE
OPPORTUNITY.CLOSEDATE = 2018 AND OPPORTUNITY.AMOUNT > 1000.00
```

Comment: You could also use an or instead of and